# Apple Script to delete file

Tags: shell, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to write an applescript to delete my sleepimage file.  The terminal command to do

```
sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage
```

Clearly I cannot just type that into the applescript editor, so I've been using this

```
do shell script rm / private / var / vm / sleepimage with administrator privileges
```

But with that I get this error

> error "The variable rm is not defined." number -2753 from "rm"

Any help would be appreciated, I know its simple, but I'm not too good with this code stuff.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just need some quotes in your miniature Applescript there.

try:

```
do shell script "rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage" with administrator privileges
```

I'll be amazed if this is what you end up using in the end though, because it's going to require you (or somebody) to type in the admin username & password each time that script is called.

Answer (score 0):

The more sensible solution is to do:

```
sudo pmset hibernatefile /dev/null
```

Then once you delete the hibernate file once, it is deleted for good.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set myPath to "/private/var/vm/sleepimage"
set usr to "username"
set pswd to "password"

do shell script "rm " & quoted form of myPath user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```